# Selenium : How to select options from a dropdown if the select tag containsstyle="display: none;"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have to perform a select action i.e select a value from a dropdown. Here is the code of my iframe:

```
<div class="js-stools-field-filter">
    <select id="filter_active" name="filter[active]" onchange="this.form.submit();" style="display: none;">
        <option value="" selected="selected">- Select Active State -</option>
        <option value="0">Activated</option>
        <option value="1">Unactivated</option>
    </select>
    <div class="chzn-container chzn-container-single chzn-container-single-nosearch chzn-container-active chzn-with-drop" style="width: 220px;" title="" id="filter_active_chzn"><a class="chzn-single"><span>- Select Active State -</span><div><b></b></div></a>
        <div class="chzn-drop">
            <div class="chzn-search">
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly="" class="active">
            </div>
            <ul class="chzn-results">
                <li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0" style="">- Select Active State -</li>
                <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1" style="">Activated</li>
                <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2" style="">Unactivated</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to select the options form the dropdown. Here is my script:

```
Select sc = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("filter_active")));
sc.selectByVisibleText("Activated");
```

But,I'm getting this error in the console:

```
Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

Can someone please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the HTML you posted, the `SELECT` is hidden because it contains `style="display: none;"`. It looks like the `<ul class="chzn-results">` and children `LI`s are the visible "dropdown" while the hidden `SELECT` holds the values after selection.

In cases like this, you can't use the `Select()` class. You will need to click the visible dropdown element (can't tell what that is... maybe the `INPUT`?) and then click the desired `LI` using normal Selenium methods.

Something like this should work...

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.chzn-search > input")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='chzn-results']/li[.='Activated']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the option with text as **Activated** as the `<select>` tag is having the attribute `style="display: none;"` you need to use the make the selection from the `<li>` tags and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.chzn-drop ul.chzn-results li.result-selected")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.chzn-drop ul.chzn-results li.active-result[data-option-array-index='1']")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='chzn-drop']//ul[@class='chzn-results']//li[contains(@class, 'result-selected')]")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='chzn-drop']//ul[@class='chzn-results']//li[contains(@class, 'active-result') and @data-option-array-index='1']")).click();
  ```